# Where is the official source code of System.IO?

Tags: haskell

Where is the official source of System.IO ?

I looked [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t%3aIO) but it is not there.

When clicking on the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/%01/%02/doc/html/src/GHC-Types.html#IO) it says that it is not here. I am confused because the other links on the [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t%3aIO) page seem to work.

EDIT:

I found this:

```
instance  Monad IO  where
    {-# INLINE return #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>)   #-}
    {-# INLINE (>>=)  #-}
    m >> k    = m >>= \ _ -> k
    return    = returnIO
    (>>=)     = bindIO
    fail s    = failIO s

bindIO :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
bindIO (IO m) k = IO $ \ s -> case m s of (# new_s, a #) -> unIO (k a) new_s
```

[here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad).

Comment: Source code or source of information ?

Comment: Clearly code, based on the links and clicking on "source"

Comment: In case it's code, this works for me: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/System-IO.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know what interface `System.IO` is supposed to expose, check the Haskell Report. I believe this is the nomative specification.

If you want the internal implementation... well, it's hard-wired into the compiler. You'd have to read through the GHC source code.

**Edit:** `IO` is special. `IO` is magical. Looking at the source for it won't tell you anything interesting. It will just be a bunch of code that manipulates the compiler's internal, low-level representation of how I/O works. Whatever you're seeking to understand, you probably won't find enlightenment here.

Comment: I wanted to see how the `>>=` is implemented. Is that in the internal implementation ?

Comment: I think GHC.Types should be there.  Doesn't look like it is.  In any case, in GHC, I believe `newtype IO a = IO (RealWorld# -> (a, RealWorld#))`, with bind implemented just like `State`.

Comment: What do those # mean ?

Comment: GHC internal stuff typically has hash marks in it. (Normally hashes aren't allowed in Haskell names. There's a language extension called "magic hash" to turn that on.) Basically a hash means it's magic. (More exactly, it means it's _unlifted_, meaning not lazy.)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid [more specifically](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/primitives.html#glasgow-unboxed), the hash means that its an unboxed type.  This brings with it strictness, but also means that the value can not ever be `undefined`.